# Using index files with Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, charisma

I want to include one theme folder https://github.com/usmanhalalit/charisma to my application.

As this document http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization , I clone the theme folder to the app/assets/charisma , and put

> config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "charisma")

to my application config.

Then I create index.js and index.css on app/assets/charisma/:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
*/


//= require_tree .
```

Then I add `//= require charisma` to my application.js ， it gave error : `couldn't find file 'charisma'` when my application run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not add the new folder to assets paths . Just clone the repository to the `vendor/assets/charisma` or `lib/assets/charisma` and there create your index files .

Answer (score 1):

At last I figured out of this. Actually I think there is an error in the documents at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#using-index-files . The index files should be named library_name.css instead of index.css(in your case create /vendor/assets/charisma/charisma.css), then in your application.css you can call //= require charisma .